# select() call in sendrcv.py is triggering an exception because of EINTR signal

Tags: python, scapy

python script is raising an exception when send() function is called.  It is because select() received EINTR signal while resolving the MAC address of the destination IP.  Can someone let me know if this is a known issue or if there is a workaround for this issue?

To debug further, when the exception was caught and called select() again, it did not raise exception second time.

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 251, in send
__gen_send(conf.L3socket(*args, **kargs), x, inter=inter, loop=loop, count=count,verbose=verbose, realtime=realtime)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 234, in __gen_send
s.send(p)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/linux.py", line 395, in send
sx = str(ll(x))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 268, in str
return self.build()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 330, in build
p = self.do_build()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 319, in do_build
pkt = self.self_build()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 310, in self_build
p = f.addfield(self, p, val)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/fields.py", line 70, in addfield
return s+struct.pack(self.fmt, self.i2m(pkt,val))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/layers/l2.py", line 95, in i2m
return MACField.i2m(self, pkt, self.i2h(pkt, x))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/layers/l2.py", line 89, in i2h
x = conf.neighbor.resolve(pkt,pkt.payload)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/layers/l2.py", line 38, in resolve
return self.resolvers[k](l2inst,l3inst)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/layers/inet.py", line 732, in <lambda>
conf.neighbor.register_l3(Ether, IP, lambda l2,l3: getmacbyip(l3.dst))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/layers/l2.py", line 73, in getmacbyip
nofilter=1)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 375, in srp1
a,b=srp(*args,**kargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 358, in srp
a,b=sndrcv(s ,x,*args,**kargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 129, in sndrcv
inp, out, err = select(inmask,[],[], remaintime)
error: (4, 'Interrupted system call')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Scapy. You can try to use the latest development version of Scapy (from [GitHub](https://github.com/secdev/scapy)) and apply the patch from pull request [#417](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/pull/417). I'll update this answer when the pull request has been merged.